# run python selenium with webdriver script then get a prefix core file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I ran a script to test the web-API, then there is a redundant file is generated under the script directory. I want to know the reason and the function of the file.
**core file**

[image]

**part of my code**

```html
import time
import requests
import pickle
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

api_one = "url_example"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('homePage_url')
print('I am sleeping for 3 seconds')
time.sleep(3)
print('open the URL')
print(driver.title)

driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(u'name')
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(u'password')
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
print('I am sleeping for 5 seconds')
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.title)
cookies=driver.get_cookies()
cookies_dict={}
for cookie in cookies:
    cookies_dict[cookie['name']] = cookie['value']
r = requests.get(api_one,cookies=cookies_dict)
print('r.status_code=')
print r.status_code
driver.quit()
print('done')
```

Comment: A process dumps core when it is terminated by the operating system due to a fault in the program. default action of certain signals is to cause a process to terminate and produce a core dump file, a disk file containing an image of the process's memory at the time of termination. This image can be used in a debugger (e.g., gdb(1)) to inspect the state of the program at the time that it terminated

Comment: it's better to use code as texts inside a code block. don't use images for that purpose. because we can't copy your code when it inside a image file

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: @stackfan  thx for your suggestion, I have post the code.